# Drag and drop multiple items Android

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to drag and drop multiple items.

Currently I have one set of Imagebuttons defined in a Linear layout, and another defined in a separate linear layout.

I'd like to make it so if you drag from a button that is not at the bottom of the layout, it will drag all items below it along with it.

With the stock drag and drop code (below) it only allows me to drag one.

```
private final class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {               
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);                
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);                
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);              
            return true;           
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

I think I might be able to move more than one view through here, but I honestly don't know that much about them.

The drag and drop area (minus my log code and whatnot) looks typical:

```
class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {
    //Drawable enterShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_droptarget);
    //Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape);

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

        int action = event.getAction();
        View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
        ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:


                // do nothing
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                //v.setBackgroundDrawable(enterShape);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                //v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
                owner.removeView(view);
                container.addView(view);  
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                //rebuildField(); works well but is clogging up the logs
                //v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by finding out a lot about views, inflaters, and layouts.

I wrote a function that finds all the ImageButtons below where the user clicked, and set them all to invisible. I then created a new Linear Layout within the Linear Layout that the user clicked, and passed that into the Drag Shadow builder.

Once into the ACTION_DROP portion, I simply referenced global variables to figure out if the user dropped in one or multiple ImageButtons, and dealt with them accordingly.

Comment: Hi GeoffM, I am facing the same issue. I am trying your method, but when I try to recreate a new LL within the LL the user clicked, I get an error stating child already exists , and that I should remove them first. you state that you set them to invisible. Would you be able to provide some more details? Thanks